# Functions Rerunning in GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using GAS to send and receive texts. There is one function that send texts (sendTexts.gs) and one that receives (receiveTexts.gs). I have both of these functions linked to individual buttons on the sheet, but when I run one function, both are running (texts get sent every time). Is there a cache or something that needs to be cleared? The receiveTexts has no commands in the code that could send messages in it, and based on logger testing, I know that both are running when I only click one.
EDIT: This also occurs in the GAS "terminal". If I click run in the script editor both run.

Here is the code with personal/individual info (codes/phone numbers edited out):

```
function sendSms(to, body) {
  var playerArray = getMeta();
  Logger.log(playerArray);
  var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/EDIT/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": to,
    "Body" : body,
    "From" : "EDIT"
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("EDIT")
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}

function sendAll() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var text = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Meta')).getRange('B4').getValue();
  var playerArray = getMeta();
  Logger.log(text);
  for (i=0; i<playerArray.length;i++) {
    try {
      var number = playerArray[i][1];
      Logger.log(number);
      response_data = sendSms(number, text);
      status = "sent";
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      status = "error";
    }
    Logger.log(status);
  }
}

function sendTexts() {
  sendAll();
}
Logger.log("ran send texts");
```

Here is the receive texts code with the same adjustments:

```
function receiveTexts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ACCOUNT_SID = "EDIT";
  var ACCOUNT_TOKEN = "EDIT";
  var toPhoneNumber = "+EDIT";
  var sheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Meta'), true);
  var playerArray = getMeta();
  var numberToRetrieve = playerArray.length;
  var hoursOffset = 0;
  var options = {
    "method" : "get"
  };
  options.headers = {
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
  };
  var url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + ACCOUNT_SID + "/Messages.json?To=" + toPhoneNumber + "&PageSize=" + numberToRetrieve;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  // -------------------------------------------
  // Parse the JSON data and put it into the spreadsheet's active page.
  // Documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Meta'), true);
  var numRounds = spreadsheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var theSheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Attacks'),true);
  var theColumn = (numRounds*2)+1;
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  for (i=0; i<dataAll.messages.length; i++){
    var sentNumber = dataAll.messages[i].from;
    Logger.log(sentNumber);
    for (k=0; k<playerArray.length;k++){
      Logger.log(playerArray[k][1]);
      if (playerArray[k][1]==sentNumber){
        var player = k;
        Logger.log('Success');
        Logger.log(player);
        break;
      }
    }
    var playerRow = playerArray[player][0];
    Logger.log(playerRow);
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Attacks'),true);
    theSheet.getRange(playerRow, theColumn).setValue(dataAll.messages[i].body);

  }
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Meta'), true);
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(numRounds +1);
}
Logger.log("texts received ran");
```

EDIT2: I separated out getMeta into a separate file. Now when I run getMeta, it also runs the other two scripts. Anytime any one script is run, all three run. This makes me think it's not related to the code, but related to some setting or something. Does the order of the scripts in the sidebar matter? I feel like that's not it because running any of the three causes all three to be run.

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible to help without seeing the code.

Comment: @Luke I added the code. I'm pretty sure it's something with the way Sheets is running the code because there are no commands in the receive texts code that could possibly send a text. I also made the function that creates a list of lists of player info separate, but was having the same issue, where when I would run it and it would run all three functions, so I just copied it in (getMeta).

Comment: I am pretty sure it can't just run them all, there must be something in there. I'd use the debugger and see what triggers it.

Comment: How would I use the debugger to do that?

Comment: A few questions: Can you post the executions a screen shot of the executions page? Why are there `Logger` calls _after_ a function, i.e. _outside_ the curly brackets? Can you put a `Logger.log()` message at the start of every function just identifying the function, so that you can look in the executions page and see the output of the executions?

Comment: @iansedano I didn't even realize those were outside, I put them in and it fixed it! Thank you!!!!